# List files in the listbox like windows explorer in Delphi

Tags: delphi, listbox

I'm listing files from a certain directory, but the listing is not the same as Windows Explorer, even if I check Sorted.

[image: Listing by name on Windows]

[image: Listing by name in the ListBox]

[image: Code]

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Code is text, and can be directly copied and pasted into your post here.

Comment: @Ken is right. Also, if you post screenshots or diagrams, don't use JPG. JPG is designed for *photographs*, and causes visible artefacts in non-photographic images with simple lines, solid-colour regions etc. Instead, please use PNG. It is perfect for screenshots and diagrams.

Answer (score 6):

You need to custom-sort the strings with a sort algorithm called "LogicalCompare".
Ingredients follow, (I hope I understand how to add code...). Also, this works in delphi10.3, don't know about previous versions.

```
uses Winapi.ShLwApi;
function LogicalCompare(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: integer): integer;
begin
  Result := StrCmpLogicalW(PWideChar(List[Index1]), PWideChar(List[Index2]));
end;
```

For your listbox-items you need a bit of a kludge, since items are of type TStrings, and Customsort only works for TStringlist. After the FindFirst etc. is finished add the
following:

```
...
var sl: TStringlist;
....//Listbox1 items are populated
sl:=TStringlist.create;
try
  sl.assign(Listbox1.items);
  sl.Customsort(LogicalCompare);
  Listbox1.items.assign(sl);
finally
  sl.free;
end;
....
```

Comment: I use Delphi XE8

Comment: It should work for all versions that have ShlWApi and for which the default string type is WideString (I missed all versions between 2006 and 10.3, sorry). If the latter is not the case you have to convert strings to Widestring before passing them to the LogicalCompare function